# В чём заключается отличие таких способов взаимодействия приложений, как шлюз и шина?

Tags: архитектура, интеграция

Читала [статью про способы взаимодействия приложений](http://mqseries.narod.ru/book/webspheremq_12.htm). И что мне осталось совершенно непонятным, это как различаются топологии интеграционного решения "шлюз" и "шина":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарна, если кто-нибудь пояснит разницу между ними.

Comment: @PavelMayorov это в оригинальной статье шлюзом и брокером называют одно

Comment: @PavelMayorov, шлюз == централизованный брокер (на картинке 3 вариант)

Comment: Ну если я не путаю, то даю аналогию. Брокер это как почта - он знает кому адресовано (вернее кому нужно доставить) и что нужно доставить и почтальон отнесет куда надо. В случае с шиной почтальон пройдет по всем квартирам с вопросом "это не вам посылка"?. Ну или роутер и свитч как примеры аналогичного поведения.

Comment: @vitidev нет, вы ошибаетесь. Шина не обязательно означает широковещание. Примеры нешироковещательных шин из мира железа - PCI-E, USB.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Неверная аналогия. Мы же не про железо говорим, где шина - это то по чем идут куда то данные,  а про подходы доставки сообщений и в программировании разница в способе адресации этих самых сообщений и кто этим занимается. Конечно в программировании шина тоже не будет всех опрашивать, она просто будет знать кто какой тип пакета ожидает и доставит только им.

Comment: да, вопрос был как раз про архитектуру софта, а не про железо; как я понимаю, применительно к софту и железу понятия "топология шина" имеет совершенно разные значения, и никак не связаны друг с другом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В статье "немного" ошиблись с определениями, отсюда и непонятки. Дело в том, что та статья написана, по сути, про одно конкретное решение - и все остальное приведено только для общего сведения.

---

**Интеграционная шина** - это прежде всего среда передачи сообщений, позволяющая доставлять сообщения на основе логических признаков. "На пальцах", это означает, что в самих сообщениях не содержатся никакие физические адреса.

Простейшие варианты интеграционных шин держат у себя справочник соответствия логических и физических адресов. Логические адреса формируются исходя из назначения приложения, его названия или оргструктуры. Этого достаточно чтобы называться шиной :)

Более сложные варианты дают возможность доставки сообщений по системе pub/sub (публикатор - подписчик).

Интеграционная шина может быть построена вокруг центрального узла (или нескольких узлов), где "крутится" маршрутизатор (см. далее) - или же быть распределенной, существуя в виде кучи адаптеров (см. далее) на стороне каждого приложения с общей базой адресов.

**Маршрутизатор сообщений** - это приложение, смысл существования которого - передавать сообщения от одного приложения к другому.

Обычно маршрутизатор сообщений можно найти внутри интеграционный шины - но не каждый маршрутизатор образует вокруг себя шину. Как минимум, нужна работа с логическими адресами.

Также маршрутизаторы сообщений иногда реализуют другие инфраструктурные сервисы, вроде гарантированной доставки, ведения журнала сообщений или преобразования форматов.

**Интеграционный шлюз** - это маршрутизатор сообщений, связи которого можно поделить на "внешние" и "внутренние".

Эти связи могут работать по одному и тому же протоколу - в таком случае смысл шлюза в разбиении общей шины на сегменты с целью добавления отказоустойчивости или защищенности. К примеру, при наличии филиалов в разных городах, в каждый можно "поставить" шлюз, который будет передавать сообщения в головной офис по шифрованному каналу.

В таком случае общая интеграционная шина окажется разбита на сегменты, которые могут продолжать ограниченно функционировать при падении интернет-канала.

Кроме того, интеграционный шлюз может соединять приложения, работающие по разным протоколам - в таком случае он будет еще и адаптером.

**Адаптер** - это маршрутизатор сообщений, разные связи которого работают по разным протоколам.

**Брокер** - это маршрутизатор сообщений повышенной <s>крутизны</s> сложности. К примеру, он может работать с децентрализованной шиной. Или выполнять хитрые трансформации, выступая универсальным центральным адаптером.

---

Как можно заметить, ни один терминов не исключает другие. Вполне можно себе представить счастье архитектора-перфекциониста в виде мега-интеграционной шины, построенной на маршрутизаторе сообщений, который является брокером, шлюзом и адаптером. Он будет уметь работать по любому протоколу, делать SQL-запросы, проводить XSLT-трансформации - и станет кошмарным сном любого разработчика :)

*Однажды я написал свой интеграционный шлюз просто потому что КРОК 2 месяца отказывался предоставлять нашей подсистеме второй адрес на своей интеграционной шине...*

А отсюда есть еще один вывод: любую достаточно сложную программу можно обозвать любым словом. Поэтому, чтобы коллеги вас понимали - старайтесь называть ее теми словами, которые используются в официальном названии программы.

К примеру, WebSphere Message Broker имеет в своем названии слово "Брокер" (и заслуженно носит его за свою непомерную <s>сложность</s> крутизну) - поэтому и называть его надо брокером, а не маршрутизатором сообщений, адаптером, шлюзом или шиной.

С другой сторону, если на основе WebSphere Message Broker был сделан свой проект по работе со СМЭВ, который был назван "шлюз для работы со СМЭВ" - то и называть его надо шлюзом, несмотря на то, что он является еще и адаптером и маршрутизатором сообщений.

Или, к примеру, сама СМЭВ по сути является простейшей интеграционной шиной, а внутрях крутится на WebSphere Message Broker (я видел типичные для него сообщения об ошибках) - но называть ее надо СМЭВ, а то не поймут.